# Combine unspecified number of dataframes in r

Tags: r, database, dataframe, automation

I need to combine some data frames with the same number of columns and rows. However, the number of data frames created has to change in each case. For example, in one case, I will need to create, name and combine 4 data frames; in another case I need to do the same for 6. The problem is that I need to find a way to name them in an atomized way, not always changing data frame variable names like a1,a2,a3,a4 in the first case and a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6 in the last case. What can I do? Thanks for the help

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please refer to the [guidelines on how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve the chances for you getting a satisfactory reply here.

Comment: [Put them in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames/24376207#24376207). Read through my answer at the linked duplicate. If you need more help after that, please ask a new question that is much more specific.